# FreeTDS says Client Driver version is not supported

Tags: sql-server, freetds

I was trying to test the PDW connectivity using tsql...
It is throwing an error as follows...

```
[tuser@apps]$  tsql -H 192.4.24.X -p 18001 -U sample_user

Password:

locale is "en_US.UTF-8"

locale charset is "UTF-8"

using default charset "UTF-8"
```

Msg 41522 (severity 20, state 1) from PdwTdsServer Line 1:

> "Client driver version is not supported."
>   Error 20002 (severity 9):
>           Adaptive Server connection failed
>   There was a problem connecting to the server

please help..

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes! What did you find?!